# JComboBox same entry multiple times

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I've got a JComboBox that I'm passing an array of strings to. Some of the values are multiple times in that array. The combobox is rendered correctly, but I just can't select all the entries.

```
String[] entrys = {"A", "B", "C", "A"};
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(entrys);
```

In this example, I won't be able to select the second `A` because there is already an `A` earlier in the array.

```
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedIndex());
    }
});
```

If I press the second `A` it's still selecting the first one and printing `0`.

- What is the best way to get this to work?
- Do I have to write a
  custom ComboBox Model?

Comment: Why do you have a second `A` in your entries?

Comment: I just need it for my UI, would take too long to explain... E.g. it could be a file name (not the full path) and if you select it it'll show you a preview if it's an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, `JComboBox` is doing this in the `getSelectedIndex` method...

```
public int getSelectedIndex() {
    Object sObject = dataModel.getSelectedItem();
    int i,c;
    E obj;

    for ( i=0,c=dataModel.getSize();i<c;i++ ) {
        obj = dataModel.getElementAt(i);
        if ( obj != null && obj.equals(sObject) )
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
```

This is why, when you select `A`, it's returning `0`, because it finds a object matching the selected value at position `0`. You need to generate a unique object wrapper around the values which will allow the comparison to select the correct value

Maybe something like...

```
public class Wrapper {
    private final String value;

    public Wrapper(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // I personally prefer to use a custom cell renderer, but 
    // for the sake of brevity, I'm using the toString method instead
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then we need to map the `String` values...

```
String[] entrys = {"A", "B", "C", "A"};
Wrapper[] wrappers = Arrays.stream(entrys).map((String t) -> new Wrapper(t)).toArray(Wrapper[]::new);
JComboBox<Wrapper> b = new JComboBox<>(wrappers);
```

and we're all set.  Just remember, you're dealing with the `Wrapper` class, not `String`s when you use `getSelectedItem`, so you'll need to unwrap them

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using a class that I can use as a wrapper (just not posted it to keep the code simple), but I didn't knew about the possibility of a custom cell renderer and I'm not able to overwrite this classes toString method. I think I'm just trying to inform myself about custom cell renderers to try it that way.